# Negative CGRectMake coordinates? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIImageView` that I'm adding to a `UIAlertController`. I want the image view to be smack dab in the middle of the screen, but when toying around with the `CGRectMake` coordinates, I'm finding that my `y` value only appears on screen if given a negative coordinate.

```
var alert = UIAlertController()
let myImage = UIImage(named: "image")
var imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2) - 60, -300, 120, 120))
imageView.image = myImage
alert.view.addSubview(imageView)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Why do I need a negative `y` value coordinate in my `var imageView` declaration to show on screen? If the `alert.view.bounds` = `(0,0,335,667)` then shouldn't a negative `y` value mean the view will appear off screen?

Otherwise, am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: [“The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) You are doing something explicitly forbidden by the documentation. So yes, you're just doing something wrong.

Comment: What would my alternative be?

Comment: Google? Custom alert view like [this one](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) for example ...

Comment: Can I use that in Swift?